# implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts in angular and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm getting this error while `ng build` or `ng serve` on Angular 11 Firebase 8.6.7

> Error: node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts:1:183 - error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
>
> 1 export function initializeApp(param: {storageBucket: string; apiKey: string; messagingSenderId: string; appId: string; projectId: string; measurementId: string; authDomain: string}) {